# Alternative of in_arrary() for object

Tags: php

I am finding the value either exists in object array in php.

I would't like to traverse whole the object array, Is their any alternative in php for object just like is_array()?

Edited:
if I var_dump($te_ws) then it shows this output . . .

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["fk_webapp_id"]=>     string(1) "3" ["fk_tenant_id"]=> string(2) "12" } [1]=>     object(stdClass)#25 (3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["fk_webapp_id"]=> string(1) "5"     ["fk_tenant_id"]=> string(2) "12" } }


$is_checked = FALSE;
if (!empty($te_ws)) {
 foreach ($te_ws as t) {
  if ($t->id === 4) {
    $is_checked = TRUE;
  }
 }
```

}

Is it possible to check the value 4 from array of object either exists using php built in function?

Comment: What is an "object array"? In PHP, objects and arrays are quite different (unlike javascript, if that is what you are familiar with).

Comment: @FrancisAvila: yah I am using object array in php - (Can find with foreach loop but it is must costly so trying best to find some function that checks :))

Comment: Can you show us some code? You can't traverse the properties of an object with foreach (which is what your question sounds like). Do you mean an iterator? Or do you mean "an array of objects"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: I have edited my question where $te_ws is an object have two values i.e id and sub_id and we are trying to find id.

Comment: What are the types of `$te_ws` and `$t`? You realize, too, that even if `$t` was an array, `in_array()` would not be useful here!

Comment: if I explore $te_ws then it shows above output that I have added it question.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: It seemed me best solution if I typecast object to array but it does't work!

Comment: this is because `id` is a string, so using === to compare to integer will always fail. and typecast to array is a ***dangerous** solution,, what if some other property of $t matches your value?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for seems very strange. What are you doing that you need to test for membership of a *value* in an object?

In simple cases you can just cast an object to an array:

```php
$object = new stdClass();
$object->a = 1;
in_array(1, (array) $object); // True
```

However this breaks down for any non-trivial object:

```
class MyClass {
    public $var1 = 1;
    private $var2 = 2;
    protected $var3 = 3;
}

$mc = new MyClass();

var_dump((array) $mc); // all properties, even private ones, are included
in_array(2, (array) $mc); // TRUE, even though you can't GET this value!
$mc->var2;  // PHP DIES with FATAL ERROR!!!!
```

The following function will get a little closer to what you describe. But it won't find properties computed with [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

```
function in_object($needle, $haystack, $strict=False) {
    if (!is_object($haystack)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("\$haystack is not an object");
    }
    $reflector = new ReflectionObject($haystack);
    $publicproperties = $reflector->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
    foreach ($publicproperties as $property) {
        $value = $property->getValue($haystack);
        if (($strict) ? $value===$needle : $value==$needle) {
            return True;
        }
    }
    return False;
}
```

Comment: Please could you suggest "in_array(1, (array) $object);" type of code why not working in our provided scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

How is your object data stored?

If it is like this:

```
class Obj
{
    public $key1 = "data";
    public $key2 = "data";
    public $key3 = "data";
    public $key4 = "data";
}
```

Then you could just call something like `isset($obj -> $key)` where `$obj` is an instance of your class and `$key` is the variable name you are looking to see if exists.

Comment: `in_array` checks value, not key.

Comment: @Tony: please let me try it :)

Comment: @WesleyvanOpdorp: exactly we want to check value not key so please is it possible with some built in function ?

Comment: This is not a good method of storing and working with data, so no appropriate method exists. However you can try http://php.net/manual/bg/function.property-exists.php

Comment: @Tony: isset will checks index but we want to compare value ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function, but you could implement something like:

```
class A {
  public $a = 'value';
  public $b = 'value2';

  public function contains($value) {
    return  in_array($value, (array)$this);
  }
}

$o = new A;
var_dump($o->contains('value2'));
var_dump($o->contains('value3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Tony saids, use http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.property-exists.php